# change color some string of textview

Tags: android, android-json

How to change color some part of string in a textview, the value come from json. I am using both Spannable class and through html, but it not be changed.

```
  if(jobject.has("posts")){

               JSONArray ar= jobject.getJSONArray("posts");
               String value=""+ar.length();
               Profile.this.post.setText(value);
               for(int i=0;i<ar.length();i++){
                   JSONObject a= ar.getJSONObject(i);
                   Pojo_profile po= new Pojo_profile();
                  // po.setUsername();
                   String blue = object.getString("user_login");

                   po.setData(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>"+blue+"</font>")+" "+a.getString("text_post"));


                   profile.add(po);
               }
```

Comment: do NOT use any `fromHtml`: use `Spannable#setSpan` instead, this is funny that 3 of 4 answers below say: use `fromHtml` and only one says: use `Spannable`, this is how bad ideas always win with good ideas... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use spans.

Example:

```
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("your text here");

// Span to set text color to some RGB value
final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(158, 158, 158)); 

// Span to make text bold
final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); 

// Set the text color for first 4 characters
sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

// make them also bold
sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); 

yourTextView.setText(sb);
```

Comment: it was my upvote, unfortunatelly i think th OP will not accept your answer and will choose much worse solution with `Html#fromHtml` ....

Comment: i have a custom listview  and the data comes in a pojo class

Comment: @pankajsynaptic so what does it change?

Comment: @pankajsynaptic so the answer is: nothing, just use `Spannable#setSpan`

Comment: tell me some example i not understand what you said.

Comment: @pankajsynaptic do you see above answer of Vinayak Mishra? what is it like not an example?

Comment: @pankajsynaptic what is not working? is  word "your" highlighted in a special way?

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("*your html text*"));
```

Call `Html.fromHtml` only while setting the text.

Answer (score 0):

AS Per Your question indicates you need to set two or more text colors on single textView then following line should work

```
      textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("blue" +"<font color=\"#000099\">"  + a.getString("text_post") + "</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

use **setAllCaps** to **false** in **SDK>=14**

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        textView.setAllCaps(false);

    }
```

and then use

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("*your html text*"));
```